# Scala style for new Object: Omit parenthesis?

Tags: scala, coding-style

The Scala Style Guide suggests omitting parenthesis when invoking an Arity-0 function if and only if that function has no side effects.

What about when creating a new object?  That is, is `val myc = new MyClass` or `val myc = new MyClass()` preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its mentioned explicitly, but elsewhere in the style guide they show creating objects as part of other examples, and they use `new MyClass`

Eg, on this page: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

Plus that's the way I do it, so what else do you need :)